# order of listener methods when session is created

Tags: jakarta-ee

What is the order of the listener methods being called when a session is created?

```
    HttpSession hs = request.getSession();
```

-->sessionCreated() of HttpSessionListener

-->valueBound() of HttpSessionBindingListener

-->attributeAdded() of HttpSessionAttributeListener

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a session is created, it contains no attribute at all, so only the HttpSessionListener would be called. And since it's the only listener called, it's also the first one :-)